# run ubuntu on windows without vt-x - very slow

Tags: virtualization, qemu, lubuntu

I want to run docker on a machine that does not support vt-x. 
Since the only solution to that would be to change machines, I installed qemu and am installed lubuntu 12 i386.

However, everything is going very slow.

Is there any way to speed it up?

I am using the following bat file:

```
@echo off

rem ==================================
rem Replace with your values
rem ==================================
set "QEMUDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Warez\qemu-2.8.0-win64"
set "ISOFILE=lubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386.iso"

rem ==================================
rem You can add a w suffix to this if 
rem you don't want a console
rem ==================================
set "QEMUBIN=qemu-system-i386.exe"

rem ==================================
rem Run the virtual machine
rem ==================================
%QEMUBIN% -drive file=ubuntu_hd.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom %ISOFILE% -m 2G -L Bios -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -boot menu=on -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -parallel none -serial none -name centos -no-hpet -no-reboot
```

Comment: Why not use a more user-friendly solution like VirtualBox?

Comment: @Daniel B I already tried with virtual vox but it failed immediately without vt-x . :(

Comment: VirtualBox only requires hardware virtualization for x64 guests, like any other virtualization software. You might want to open a *new* question about getting VirtualBox to work, with error messages, settings and whatnot.

Comment: @daniel-b That's a great point... I had tried with 64 bit version of the ISO when I tried virtual box. Will try the 32 bit now!

Comment: @daniel-b Actually, it seems that I had forgotten the limit on ram as well (for 32 bit). Must be less than 4gb.

Comment: @daniel-b I came across KQEMU that was supported in the 2015 releases. Apparently in 2016 they changed the wiki page on KQEMU to obsolete features (in favor of KVM). Gowever, since virtualbox seems to be working I didn't progress further.